# Powershell / Combining two scripts

Tags: powershell

Morning Stack overflow,

Got an issue trying to combine these two PowerShell scripts. When a computer pings back, put it in an excel sheet and run this command. When it does nothing just put in the excel sheet as failed. Here is what I have so far. The excel sheet is created but the command does not run?

```
$Results = Get-Content -path c:\scripts\noclient.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1) {
        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        'Computer Name' = $_
        'Ping Status' = 'Ok'
        }
    } else {
        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
        'Computer Name' = $_
        'Ping Status' = 'Failed'
        }
    }
}


$Results | Export-Csv -Path c:\scripts\PingStatus.csv -NoTypeInformation

$Results | Where-Object { $_.'Ping Status' = 'Ok' } | ForEach-Object {
    $vmhost = $_.'Computer Name'
    $dest = "\\"+$vmhost+"\C$\Windows\temp"
    copy-item "\\path\to\ccmsetup.exe" -Destination $dest -Force
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vmhost -ScriptBlock{
    $Exp = "cmd.exe /c C:\windows\temp\CCMSetup.exe /mp:servername /nocrlcheck /usepkicert smsmp=servername smssitecode=123"
    Invoke-Expression $Exp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `-eq` instead of `=` in the second part of your script, when you check the `Ping Status`, ie.:

```
$Results | Where-Object { $_.'Ping Status' -eq 'Ok' } | ...
```

Comment: The above answer was the fix for my script.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a CSV file is **not** an Excel file. CSV is a text file with structured (delimited) data that can be imported in Excel.

Next, I would use `Start-Process` instead of `Invoke-Expression` and why start cmd.exe to run CCMSetup.exe?

I cannot test this myself, but please try

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vmhost -ScriptBlock {
    $params = '/mp:servername', '/nocrlcheck', '/usepkicert', 'smsmp=servername', 'smssitecode=123'
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\windows\temp\CCMSetup.exe" -ArgumentList $params
}
```

Also, the `=` is an assignment, not a [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)
`$_.'Ping Status' = 'Ok'` --> `$_.'Ping Status' -eq 'Ok'`

Comment: I apologize you are correct I meant CSV not Excel file. For some reason it still is not starting the install. I used the cmd.exe only because it was suggested on another site and seemed to work. (By itself of course)   Good to know about = vs the -eq. I did change that.  I wonder if it would work if I just did the first part and have it call another PS script instead of putting it in the script itself? Of course it also not only won't start the install but says the "Cannot find path" for the server share. Which of course is there and valid.